# Fixing the text size in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

Tell me please, has OpenLayers the ability to fix text on a layer so that its size does not change when zooming. I draw areas on the layer using polygons. Each area has a name, which I place in the center of the polygon. When zooming, the names go beyond the polygons or hide under other objects.

Is it possible to fix the size of the text relative to the polygons?

Any information on working with text will be useful!

Comment: The style function is passed resolution as well as the feature, so you can use that to scale text, icons, etc.  https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-3ofeq

Comment: Thanks! I understand correctly, is it necessary to redraw the text (change the style) every time when zooming?

Comment: Yes, for a smooth effect you should specify `updateWhileAnimating` and `updateWhileInteracting` in the layer options - the extra rendering may affect performance.